# How does postgres host based authentication work?

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804806/how-does-postgres-host-based-authentication-work

(I was asked to shift this query to DBA.Stackexchange)

I am installing DSPACE which needs Postgresql.

Please see this link: [DSPACE INSTALL](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace)

It says:

> Then tighten up security a bit by editing pg_hba.conf and adding this line:
>
> ```
> host dspace dspace 127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255 md5.
> ```

I have read on the internet as to how the above line works. It needs a connection type followed by database name/user name followed by IP address and the authentication scheme.

My query is: Should this not be a local (in place of host) connection since the dspace user is running locally?

Can someone show me step by step as to what happens when a request comes in?
Where are the instructions that the dspace user will submit a request using md5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `local` connection uses a Unix-domain socket; a `host` connection uses TCP.
The linked page says that

> you need to enable TCP/IP connections (DSpace uses JDBC)

… because JDBC does not have built-in support for Unix-domain sockets.

As long as a connection is allowed only from `localhost` (as configured in `pg_hba.conf`) and only to `localhost` (as configued by `listen_addresses`), it is as secure as a `local` connection.

The `md5` is just an option that specifies how the password is to be encrypted during the connection setup; this is handled automatically by the JDBC driver. For a local connection, or for a connection over SSL, this does not really matter.

Comment: After some quick Googling, you might be able to use unix sockets with the Postgres JDBC driver version 9.4-1208 or higher. See https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CALU_HCMmpQejODHSoq82K2o=q97t63vODqKj+hyt2WabOYcm-A@mail.gmail.com

Comment: @Colin'tHart The driver has a socket factory, but no Unix-domain socket implementation, and  that would not be possible in Java without JNI.

Comment: Seems doable: https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket